Use registered trademark symbol every time the trademark appears, or just the first?
I am sending a corporate email. The copy contains several instances of a registered trademark. Do I need to include the ® symbol with every use of the trademark, or just the first one?

Best practice (which is very common) is to use it every time the registered trademark is used.
But ultimately, if push came to shove, one use of it in a single email would probably be legally sufficient to make a registered trademark claim, because that puts the reader on notice of the claim that the mark is registered.
